# How to use MKRoute to create specific path?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit

I'm relatively new to the iOs scenario, so this may be a dumb question but anyways...

I've been working on a project, and I wanted to do a specific route highlighted on the map. For exemple: A bus's itinerary is always the same, so I'd like to highlight the streets that the bus goes through before reaching his final destination.

The thing is I was only able to get directions from one point to another, but it does not follow the bus's itinerary, so it does not work for me.

Please help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First if you require specific route you will need some of its coordinates. Let's say you have some route coordinates as `NSDictionary` objects like in the example below

```
{
 Lat = 53.3478;
 Lon = -6.2597;
}
```

Stored in `NSArray` called `routeLocations` then you can do the following:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D routeCoord[routeLocations.count];
for (int i = 0; i < routeLocations.count; i++ )
{
 id location =[routeLocations objectAtIndex:i];
 routeCoord[i] = CLLocationCoordine2DMake([[location objectForKey:@"Lat"]floatValue], [[location objectForKey:@"Lon"]floatValue]);
}
// create your route Polyline
MKPolyline *poly = [MKPolyline polylineWithCoordinates:routeCoord count:routeLocations.count];

// first remove previously added overlays if any then add your newly created route polyline
[self.mapView addOverlay:poly];
```

If you require customization on your overlay you can implement the following
For iOS >= 7

```
-(MKOverlayRenderer *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView rendererForOverlay:(id<MKOverlay>)overlay
{
  if ([overlay isKindOfClass:[MKPolyline class]])
  {
    MKPolyline *route = overlay;
    MKPolylineRenderer *routeRenderer = [[MKPolylineRenderer alloc]initWithPolyline:route];
    routeRenderer.strokeColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    return routeRenderer;
  }
}
```

Else use deprecated method

```
-(MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id<MKOverlay>)overlay
{
  if ([overlay isKindOfClass:[MKPolyline class]])
  {
    MKPolylineView *route = [[MKPolylineView alloc]initWithPolyline:overlay];
    route.strokeColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    return route;
  }
}
```